# How can I transfer data from BigQuery to sftp?

Tags: google-bigquery, sftp

I am trying to figure out the best way to go about automating a specific query that would pull data from BQ on daily basis and sends it via SFTP. For context, currently see related tables on console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=name and query those tables on the BQ SQL console.

I could export this data to csv format (depending on size) and then send it using filezilla via sftp, but I am trying to avoid having to do this manually.

What kind of tools would I need to use? And the steps needed in order to accomplish this?

Comment: you can create a cloud function (that can be triggered via cloud scheduler) that will run a specific query on BigQuery and export that data to GCS. From there you can create an GCS file upload event based trigger to a cloud run  where your logic to send data to sftp endpoint will exist. This is a little complex overall but one way to automate eveything.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#python

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications